# UnsatisfiedDependencyException Spring MVC project context root issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

edit: added @Repository and @Service to UserDAOImpl and UserServiceImpl classes as per user7294900 and  @skhussain suggestions, however I'm still getting a similar stack trace (updated with below)

I'm creating a web app with Spring MVC using Hibernate, REST and Maven. I can reach my index.jsp page fine, however trying to reach my REST mapping gives me the following stack trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/BootstrapContext;)V
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've had a similar issue like this before with a Spring MVC project and it required updating my dependencies within pom.xml. However I feel I've gone through the dependencies and code a million times without any luck!

/remixapp/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>co.uk.nightmarengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>remixapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>remixapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.13</mysql.connector.version>
        <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>

        <springsecurity.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Commons logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>spring-crm-rest</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/config/SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java:

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/config/AppConfig.java

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;               
    }

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }   

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/resources/persistence-mysql.properties:

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/remix_webapp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.user=<username>
jdbc.password=<password>

connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000


hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.packagesToScan=co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.entity
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/entity/User.java

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="enabled")
    private int enabled;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="picture_file")
    private String pictureFile;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, int enabled, String createdAt) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPictureFile() {
        return pictureFile;
    }

    public void setPictureFile(String pictureFile) {
        this.pictureFile = pictureFile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password
                + ", enabled=" + enabled + "]";
    }

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/dao/UserDAOImpl.java:

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.entity.User;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<User> query = currentSession.createQuery(
                "from User", User.class);
        List<User> users = query.getResultList();

        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/service/UserServiceImpl.java:

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.dao.UserDAO;
import co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.entity.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {  
        return userDAO.getUsers();  
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/java/co/uk/nightmarengine/remixapp/rest/UserRestController.java:

```
package co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.entity.User;
import co.uk.nightmarengine.remixapp.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userService.getUsers();
    }

}
```

/remixapp/src/main/webapp/index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/users">Get All Users</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally the context root always defaults to 'spring-crm-rest' even if I change it to 'remixapp' within Properties -> Web Project Settings..? I'm not sure why - 'spring-crm-rest' was a previous project but this string is declared absolutely nowhere in my code.

With that in mind, I can reach 'http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/ without any issues (which points to index.jsp). However requesting 'http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/api/users' gives me the above stacktrace.
In fact, entering anything after the root context path gives me the same error, e.g. 'http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/fghfg'

I had confirmed my app could connect to the MySQL database, however that was through a basic servlet which wasn't reading from my pom.xml.
I've also tried clearing cache from Tomcat, cleaning my project, deleting dependencies from my local maven repo, updating project's maven dependencies -> in-case there's some cache issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [@Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotation to `UserServiceImpl` so it'll be known to Spring as a Service class

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
```

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service"

Also add `@Repository` to `UserDAOImpl` follow @skhussain comment

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
```

Comment: @Repository//missing in you file
         public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

Comment: Wow thank you! I can't believe I missed those. However I'm still getting a similar error after adding those two: `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory';`

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out! It seems this dependency is conflicting with other Hibernate packages:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

After removing it + adding the suggestions from @user7294900 and @sk hussain I've fixed the issue :)